# How to extract input tag value from a javascript generated HTML page, using PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I need some help.
I have a javascript generated html page like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="http://www.123.com/ProgressiveTickers/include/js/ProgressiveTickersMandatory.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="myid">
<div style='padding:7px;'><script src='http://www.456.com/modules/common/getProgBlock.php?progid=1&cbox=all&showlogo=yes&currency=USD'></script>
</div>
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This will generate this piece of code that I'm interested in:

...

```
<input id="progressive1" class="progressiveInput" type="text" style="background-color:Transparent;border-width:0px;width:100px;text-align:center;" readonly="readonly" value="1841576" name="progressive1">
```

...

I would like to extract the value="1841576" (so, '1841576') from this input tag.
I know, I need to parse the javascript file. I tried many methods but without success.

Getting crazy.

How can I extract the value from this input tag (javascript generated) with PHP?

Any helps would be very appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Put your input tag inside a form element and submit the form.  The value of the input tag will then be in the POST header.

Comment: Hello Nickoli, thank you for your reply. The input tag is generated by an external JS. How can I insert it into a form element?

Comment: add <form> tags around whatever JS generates that tag.